# Best load testing tools for Symfony2

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

I have a question about the load testing tools that can help my website developed with Symfony2 to ensure good performance.

I'm really new about testing so I need to know the best open source tools to use for Symfony2?

Comment: How is load testing with symfony2 different from any other load testing (even in other languages)? Have a look at `ab` ("Apache Benchmark", part of Apache-Webserver) or google page speed.

Comment: Ok so the best is Apache Benchmark ,I need more I found JMeter...